# meaning of 'would have to'

Tags: modal-verbs

> I **would have to** believe that the only logical way for my life to
>   go after the riots in 2001 was to dream-up a non-profit called
>   InkTank, to encourage anybody who ever wanted to set things on fire to
>   write down the deepest, most hidden part of their hearts. ([Kathy
>   Holwadel](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/15305/))

Is *would have to* the back-shifted form of *will have to*, or the non-past modal remoteness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence before the one you quoted is necessary to understand the usage:

> Because if that were true, that there’s a plan, it would mean there’s a reason I live in Cincinnati, Ohio and my son robs banks. I would have to believe that ...

Removing the intervening text, the important parts are "Because if that were true, ... I would have to believe ..."

I'm probably going to mess up the grammatical terms, but I think this is just the normal *subjunctive mood*, expressing the consequences of a contrafactual supposition.

**Edit**: On further reading, I think this usage is not *subjunctive*. Instead, it's called a [*conditional*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences), specifically the "second conditional", according to the Wiki article.