# a question about grammar of " Would have to "

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

Consider:

> She hoped for a future when marriage **would not have** to end a career of research.

I have read below questions however,They are not answering my question

1. > [link 1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/had-to-go-vs-would-have-to-go), (answer: **Would is used here to express repeated or habitual action in the past**)

In this case, can we use two auxiliary verbs in a chain consecutively ?
I mean **would** and **have to**

You suggest that: "when I was a kid, I would must do our homework"

1. > [link 2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42824/must-vs-would-have-to-in-indirect-speech) , this is irrelevant (conditional usage of would)
2. > [link 3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9411/meaning-of-would-have-to), No grammarian explanation can be seen there.

---

Comment: There is no need for the apology or the plea at the end, and I have edited it out: this question is a model to all users of how to use the site! Thank you!

Comment: You guys are awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the "ordinary" use of *will* to signify future reference, backshifted into the past-tense form because the 'future' being spoken of is future with respect to a point in the past.

If that's too hard to follow, look at it this way:

If she were experiencing hope now, in the present, we would say:

> She **hopes**<sup>PRESENT-TENSE FORM</sup> for a future when marriage **will**<sup>PRESENT-TENSE FORM</sup> not have to end a career of research.

But we are talking about her experiencing hope at some time in the past, so we 'backshift' the present-tense forms into past-tense forms.

> She **hoped**<sup>PAST-TENSE FORM</sup> for a future when marriage **would**<sup>PAST-TENSE FORM</sup> not have to end a career of research.

As for *have to* with *would*: you cannot use modals like 'must' this way, because they don't have the necessary infinitive form to combine with *would*. But one reason why *have to* is now replacing *must* is precisely because *have* **does** have an infinitive (and other non-finite forms), so it permits this use. *Have* is not being used syntactically as an auxiliary, even though it has a modal **sense**, but as a lexical verb.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a case in which the tense of the verb changes to coincide with the other tense.  If we rewrite the example in Present Tense, we get

> She **hopes** for a future when marriage **will** not have to end a career of research.

Since the Past Tense is used, the auxiliary verb *will* is transformed into *would* ("Future in the Past").

Comment: I like your formatting more.

Comment: But yours says the same thing in a lot fewer words. "Less is more" -Mies van der Rohe